# Vue Routing Tabs Back History

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, single-page-application

Hello to the comunity of vue developers, I have a problem, and I hope you can help me.
I will show 3 states on my structure.

Route: '/tab1'
[image: Route: '/tab1']

Route: '/tab1/item1'
[image: Route: '/tab1/item1']

Route : '/tab2'
[image: Route : '/tab2']

So, as you can see, here I have the tipical structure, about list/item.
The problem, is this is a SPA, embebed in a webapp for ios and android (simulating app).
So, when the user is in state 'tab1/item1', then change to 'tab2', and then click to 'tab1', internally, it should do like a return, but not go to 'tab1', it should go to 'tab1/item1' (as back history, not reloading the page).
Do you know if this is already created or a structure?
I was thinking to about to use multiple views, inside each tab, and not only 1 main view for all.
Another think, was removing views, and use parent component.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could save which item was selected in each tab before leaving said tab page, then reload that information when user returns to the tab.

Back history can be implemented but the user would need to press back instead of the tab. I do not know of an already created structure that would fit what you want.